# Find n largest element positions in an 2D Array

Tags: c++, optimization

How to find '**n**' largest element positions in a 2D array?
Is there a good algorithm, other than brute force?

Any suggestions are helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the n largest elements (and their positions) in a two-dimensional array as efficiently as you can in a one-dimensional array.

There are [a variety of selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) that run in linear time.  Quickselect has linear average time complexity but, like Quicksort, can be quadratic in the worst case.  The median-of-medians algorithm has both expected and worst case linear time complexity.

Of course, if the elements are sorted, then this is trivial:  go to the end of the array and select the required number of elements from there.  This may take a little logic depending on how the array is sorted in two dimensions, but it's not difficult.